# Why isn't my sticky footer working?

Tags: html, css, layout, sticky-footer

I'm trying to make a sticky footer, but it's not quite working for me.

CODE: http://jsfiddle.net/PC8x7/1/

As you can see in the live view, the footer comes underneath the rest of the page but you have to scroll to get there. How can I avoid this, and only have it have a scroll bar when it needs to?

Comment: you have to see the note in sticky footer that margins of the containers break the footer

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code here.  If JSFiddle becomes inaccessible, your question will be useless as it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to get rid of the margins in the main containers and headers

see the note about heights and margins http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html

Comment: Your answer just blended in with the others. Sorry about that. I should learn to pay more attention because it's RIGHT! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I was giving up :)

Comment: If anyone else can vote this up for me I'd be ever so grateful

Answer (score 1):

Your wrapper has `min-height: 100%;` and your footer is placed underneath the wrapper. The wrapper is 100% of the height of the page and the footer is put right underneath the page forcing the scroll.

There's a couple ways you can get around the issue. You can try putting the footer inside the wrapper, setting wrapper's position to relative, and absolute positioning the footer to the bottom.

css:

```
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.footer-link {
    text-align: center;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  ...

  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footerlink">
      <p><span>&copy; Domain.tld</span> | </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: By taking away the "position: relative;" in .wrapper it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

As i understand - you want to put footer on the bottom of the window ?

method A. - make it position: fixed

method B. - play around with wrapper height 100%, overflow and border-box 
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html . You can put footer over wrapper padding this way

method C. - Javascript

Comment: No, he is looking for a 'sticky footer'. `position:fixed` is for positioning it to the bottom of the window. A sticky footer sticks to the bottom of the page.

Comment: This will break when the page content needs to scroll.

Comment: method B will not - because scrolling is in wrapper, not in window